# Bind SelectedItem to property on VM

Tags: xaml

In my Xaml I have this listview:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      Height="355" 
                      Margin="144,373,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      Width="154"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310x260ItemTemplate}"/>
```

And on my VM i have this property:

```
private Person _selectedItem;
        public Person SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedItem;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_selectedItem == value || value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var oldValue = _selectedItem;
                _selectedItem = value;

                // Update bindings, no broadcast
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
```

What im hoping for is that the SelectedItem-property on my VM would get updated whenever I click an item in the listview. Can someone see what I am missing here?

Comment: Show the code how you handle the people property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If it doesn't work, in page constructor add:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

It should work now.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, its something like this i am after. I´d prefer if had did not have to add code in the codebehind.

Comment: Is it working now? Or should i provide more information?

Comment: No, it does not work. If I put a breakpoint on my property on the viewmodel, it never gets hit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)